# Is it possible to boot from one GRUB installation to another GRUB installation?

Tags: grub2

For example, I have one main GRUB installation, and I want to have a menu entry in there that boots me into a second GRUB installation.

This is probably an XY problem. My main GRUB installation doesn't let me use the loopback command. It just says that the loopback command isn't found, and yes, I did try using the module 'loopback'. I think that the problem has something to do with the fact that I have an encrypted boot partition. So my 'solution' is to install a second GRUB, which I boot into through the main GRUB menu.

Comment: Have a look at the [chainloader feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Chain_002dloading.html). You should be able to load the other bootloader with that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

"Use Super Grub Disk"
https://www.supergrubdisk.org/

I hope I have helped.

Comment: It would be great if you could expand this answer a little, explaining how to use this tool and what it does.

Comment: Thank you for your denial. As you may have noticed, I gave a hint (link) on how I could resolve the question. Because the site is super simple and with detailed information, I believe copying and pasting would not be the best thing to do here.

Comment: Denial? What do you mean? I just said it would be better if you could add some details. Link-only answers [are not considered valid](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/203101) here. If your link breaks, for example, your answer will no longer be helpful. If you're referring to the downvote, that wasn't me.